# HTTP connection to VM Instance on google cloud fails despite checking firewall rules

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, rstudio-server

I have a google cloud platform VM instance on which I have installed [Rstudio server](https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/). I am trying to navigate to the RStudio Server browser interface using the VM’s External IP address (following tutorials such as [this](https://grantmcdermott.com/2017/05/30/rstudio-server-compute-engine/)). But connection fails.
I have done the following with regard to connection permission and firewall: 
1) I have enabled HTTP traffic, 2) I have created a firewall rule: gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-rstudio --allow=tcp:8787.

Comment: What is configured for `www-port` and `www-address`?

Answer (score 1):

I have followed all the steps of the guide you shared [RStudio Server on Google Compute Engine](https://grantmcdermott.com/2017/05/30/rstudio-server-compute-engine/) and I was able to connect via Chrome browser to the 'rstudio' VM located in GCP environment using http://EXTERNAL-IP-ADDRESS:8787.

Please

- Verify that there is no firewall denying this connection and if the firewall rule to 8787 was created in the network of the 'rstudio' VM
- Also, is there an error message when trying to connect?
- Were you able to connect directly from terminal using:
  root@rstudio:~# R

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was not logged as root, but as an additional user.